# tricky Trigonometry triangle question

Tags: trigonometry

ABC is right-angled triangle with right angle at the corner of C and angle v degrees at the corner B.

Which of following is true, might be many answers correct:

1. |AC| = |AB|sin v
2. |AB| = |AC|sin v
3. |AC| = |BC| tan v
4. |BC| = |AB| cos v
5. |BC| = |AB| tan v

I think it's 2 and 4 that're correct but I don't know how to solve this at all.

Comment: Why do you think 2 and 4 are correct? Please show some working and thinking of your own.

Comment: because AB is bigger than AC I don't know really I need help please

Comment: Have you drawn the triangle being described, including the angles? If so can you then apply the usual trigonometric equations for triangles?

Comment: I'm not good at mathematics please can you help me

Comment: I'm asking question because I dont know how to solve it

Comment: Are you familiar with the trigonometric equations? Normally abbreviated to SOC CAH TOA in engish?

Comment: Okay I think I solved it EHH!!! Is the answer: 1, 3 and 4 are correct!?

Comment: I looked up definitions for trigonometry and then I just draw triangle and it shows 1, 3 and 4 are correct is it true?

Comment: The answer you posted in the comments is correct.  I suggest you answer your own question, so that it can be closed.

Comment: @Vladimir yes you're right, as the previous comment says you should now post your solution as an answer so that other people who are looking this up can see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to know the definitions of the trig functions. I'll give you a mnemonic: soh, cah, toa.
S is sine, c is cosine, t is tangent. O is the side opposite, a is adjacent, and h is hypotenuse.
You're using sine which is 'soh'. Sinv=opposite/hypotenuse. Let v be the angle you described.
If you draw the triangle and use this mnemonic with just a tiny amount of algebra you'll have your answer.